# Removing Apple Maps Default Annotations

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, apple-maps

I have been building an app that pins places to a map and have been using Apple Maps for it thus far. However, I've noticed that when zoomed in, the default POI annotations that Apple has included in its maps are quite distracting and make the map feel cluttered when I add my own annotations to the map as well.

I am searching for a way to turn these POIs off in the API but have yet to find the correct property or method to do so.

Just to note, it does appear possible as the new OpenTable app is using Apple Maps, but has found a way to remove these POI annotations. I would post images of each to show the difference, but apparently I need 10 reputation points to do this!

If anyone can even point me to a link that will show me how to remove these, I'm happy to read documentation.

Comment: I voted up your question and that should give you just enough rep to attach images if you will edit this question to include the images.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) there is a `showsPointsOfInterest` as of iOS 7, just set it to `NO` (ObjC) or `false` (Swift).

Comment: I'd vote this up twice if I could. A google search for the past 10 minutes didn't reveal any answers. It's difficult to search for something if you're not quite sure what term to search for.

Comment: Reading the documentation for the class you are trying to search about is probably a good first step. It's more productive than Google for the reasons you cite, and you may learn the answer to your next question before you even ask it! The documentation is quite good.

Comment: Hello, it's someone from the future. While this answer is technically correct, it does not work as intended on iOS 11.1. Annotations are still visible even when `showsPointsOfInterest` is set to `false`.